# addSublayer over video preview in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add a simple text label over a video preview. The video preview works fine, but the text label is no where to be found.  The compiler isn't giving me any errors or warnings either. I know I'm mixing dot notation in there, but I'm not sure if that's my root cause or not.

This is a clip from my .m file:

```
@interface AVRecorderDocument ()
    @property (retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTextField *labelVideoOverlay;
@end

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController
{
    CALayer *previewViewLayer = [[self previewView] layer];

    self.labelVideoOverlay = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 120, 200, 40)];
    self.labelVideoOverlay.stringValue = @"TEST";
    self.labelVideoOverlay.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    self.labelVideoOverlay.textColor = [NSColor whiteColor ];

    [previewViewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack)];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[self session]];
    [newPreviewLayer setFrame:[previewViewLayer bounds]];

    [newPreviewLayer setAutoresizingMask:kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable];

    [previewViewLayer addSublayer: self.labelVideoOverlay.layer];
    [previewViewLayer addSublayer:newPreviewLayer];

    [self setPreviewLayer:newPreviewLayer];
    [newPreviewLayer release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like although you've added the video preview as a sublayer, you still need to add the overlay as a subview to your main view. I did something similar like this recently (just with an `UIImageView`), but the principal should still be the same.

```
self.overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlaygraphic.png"]];
self.overlayImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[[self view] addSubview:self.overlayImageView];
```

So, you could do something like:

```
self.labelVideoOverlay = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 120, 200, 40)];
self.labelVideoOverlay.stringValue = @"TEST";
self.labelVideoOverlay.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];
self.labelVideoOverlay.textColor = [NSColor whiteColor ];
[[self view] addSubview:self.labelVideoOverlay];
```

Comment: That did it. I had to just change [self view] to [self previewView]. Thanks!

Comment: virtual bonus points, if you can tell me how to get the label background clear.  NSColor clearColor only made it white.